# Access cross tenant Storage Account (firewall protected) from Az Synapse (dedicated SQL pool) in a different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-synapse

I have a Az Synapse (dedicated SQL pool) configured with managed VNet in tenant A and storage account in tenant B. The storage account is firewall protected and only certain VNets and IPs can access it. I want to created external tables from the Az synapse and hence, access the Storage account residing in the other tenant.

I have created a private endpoint on the storage account using Az synapse and the necessary IAM roles are in place.
The external table is created and I can retrieve the data when the firewall on storage account is lifted.

However, when the storage account firewall is enabled, I get the following error:

```
Msg 105019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message:
HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://someadlsl001.dfs.core.windows.net/somecontainer/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90'
```

The SQL queries used in synapse workspace SQL script is

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL cred WITH IDENTITY = '{clientID of service principal}@https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/token', SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureDataLakeStore
WITH ( LOCATION = 'abfss://somecontainer@someadlsl001.dfs.core.windows.net/weather.csv' , CREDENTIAL = cred, TYPE = HADOOP ) ;


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[WeatherData2] (
    [usaf] [nvarchar](100) NULL
    
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION='/',
    DATA_SOURCE = AzureDataLakeStore,
    FILE_FORMAT = csvFile,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
);

select * from [dbo].[WeatherData2]
```

Please help

Comment: Any help is appreciated

Comment: Still awaiting an answer on this. Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data when the firewall on storage account is disabled. It shows There is an issue with Role assignment.

You need to make sure User is assigned with Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal.

[image]

Also make sure you whitelist IP address.

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/648148/spark-pool-notebook-error.html

Comment: I have added the Storage Blob Data Contributor and also the owner role. Still the error remains. Also, when I remove the firewall and enable access to all networks on the storage account, the error is gone and I can see the data.

Comment: Is this happening because both the resources (synapse and ADLS) are on different tenants?

Answer (score 0):

> Configuration of rules that grant access to subnets in virtual networks that are a part of a different Azure Active Directory tenant are currently only supported through PowerShell, CLI and REST APIs. Such rules cannot be configured through the Azure portal, though they may be viewed in the portal.*

**[Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-powershell#required-permissions)*

You mention your firewall is configured to allow only certain VNets & IPs. You might need to elaborate for us on what your rules are specifically, but the documentation is very clear on how this is configured when accessing the storage account from another tenant.

AZ CLI:

```
az storage account network-rule add -g myRg --account-name mystorageaccount --subnet $subnetId
```

Az Powershell:

```
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "myRg" -Name "mystorageaccount" -VirtualNetworkResourceId $subnetId
```

---

And this might be stating the obvious, but any IP range in the IP address whitelist only applies to the public endpoints of the storage account. Keep that in mind if you're trying to whitelist resources accross tenants or on-premise.

Comment: Oh, and I recommend you edit your question and obfuscate the endpoint and blob path thats in the error message you included.

Comment: Please note that VNet of Synapse is not directly visible to us. It is a managed VNet of Azure. Hence, I cannot whitelist this at the site of the storage account using the commands you have mentioned above. This is the reason I created a private endpoint for the storage account.

Comment: I see. I realized now after posting and going through some more documentation, the firewall doesn't apply to private endpoint traffic. So this apparently isn't routed correctly.

You mention having created a private endpoint for the storage account. Would this be the private endpoint on storage account resource? The requirement for private traffic from a Synapse Workspace in another tenant is a [**Managed** private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-create-managed-private-endpoints) (remember to approve it after creation).

Comment: Yes. I have followed the exact same steps and approved the endpoint also. I can the status as approved on synapse as well.

Comment: Is this issue specifically through the dedicated SQL pool? Are you able to explore the data through the Synapse workspace storage explorer?

Comment: Do you mean a linked service to Storage Account in Synapse?